# storing the mysqli result into array and then printing it with a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, mysqli

hello i am trying to store the result of mysqli query into an array and then store the array into session and then printing the session veriable with the help of mysqli_fetch_array on other pages..

my code looks like ....

```
      $arraysession=array();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['query_result'])){
 $GEttheBIrthdaYS=mysqli_query($conn,"select something from tablename where (something=something1) order by id desc limit 40");
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_row($GEttheBIrthdaYS)){
    array_push($arraysession, $res);
 }$_SESSION['query_result']=$arraysession;
 } else {
 $GEttheBIrthdaYS = $_SESSION['query_result'];
}
 while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($GEttheBIrthdaYS)){
  }
```

the array is stored into session and i can even print the array by

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($GEttheBIrthdaYS,1),'</pre>';
```

when i print the array it is like

```
    Array
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 160
        [1] => name1
        [2] => image
        [3] => 1995-05-28 00:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 158
        [1] => name2
        [2] => image.jpg
        [3] => 1994-06-14 00:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 157
        [1] => name3
        [2] => image.jpg
        [3] => 1995-01-15 00:00:00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 155
        [1] => name4
        [2] => image.jpg
        [3] => 1993-08-26 00:00:00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 154
        [1] => name5
        [2] => image.gif
        [3] => 1993-09-27 00:00:00
    )

   )
```

the problem is when i print the array with mysqli_fetch_array it shows

```
  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in f/:something/directory/page on line 3
```

i just want to know how can i print this array stored into session by while loop 
i need to print then as

```
 while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($GEttheBIrthdaYS)){
 echo $data['dob']; ..........     
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've converted the row from a `mysqli_result` to an `array`, so you need to iterate over the array and then print it out, something like this should work:

```
foreach($GEttheBIrthdaYS as $data) {
    echo $data[0];
    echo '<br>'.$data[1];
    echo '<br>'.$data[2];
    echo '<br>'.$data[3];
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. I think it will depend upon when you run the code, the first time you run the code `$GEttheBIrthdaYS` is of type `mysqli_result`, and get's placed into the session as an `array`. Then the second time you run the code, the data is in the session, and at that point `$GEttheBIrthdaYS` is now an array. My code should work for the second run.

Comment: i have made it to run in the first turn also .. :p thankx it worked ... :)

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query might be failing and returning a false value.

put this after your mysqli_query() to see whats going on.

```
if (!$$GEttheBIrthdaYS) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
```